# mottie tablesorter destroy, destroys look and feel of table

Tags: tablesorter

I've been using phantomjs and wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF reports of large 7000 row bootstrapped themed tables with color.  Both run out of memory when trying to do so.  Both uses nearly 1GB of memory to try to generate the PDF of the table.  So I've been trying to figure out why.  I want to first try to unlink tablesorter and clear it's cache when I'm printing a PDF report because it doesn't need any user interaction (no sorting or filtering needed).  But everytime I use destroy, it destroys the look and feel of the table.  I want to retain the look and feel but only destory tablesorter stuff like widgets and cache so that it doesn't consume so much memory.  Is there a way to clear tablesorter but retain the look and feel of my table?

Update:
Thanx for replying Mottie!

I actually tried that and debugged and found that this is how the  DOM looks like with tablesorter enabled with bootstrap theme:

```
<table data-bind="if: details" id="ColorTable-sticky" class="tablesorter tablesorter-bootstrap table table-bordered hasFilters containsStickyHeaders tablesorter-sticky-hidden" style="position: fixed; margin: 0px; top: 40px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 2; height: 0px; width: 1190px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; left: 36px;">
```

But once I destroy(false), I get this:

```
<table data-bind="if: details" id="ColorTable-sticky" class="tablesorter">
```

I would have thought that "tablesorter-bootstrap" class would be retained in the class but it appears that all classes were removed except for "tablesorter" class.

How do I get it to retain the tablesorter-bootstrap class?

Answer (score 0):

The [destroy method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#destroy) does have parameters:

```
// Remove tablesorter and all classes but the "tablesorter" class on the table
// callback is a function
$("table").trigger("destroy", [false, callback]);
```

If you pass `false` as the first parameter, everything is still destroyed, but the "tablesorter" class, including the theme name (e.g. "tablesorter-blue"), is retained.

The sort arrows are removed as well.

---

Update: Oh, I guess the "tablesorter-bootstrap" class is removed because it is part of the "uitheme" widget. I'll look into that. In the mean time, use the destroy callback function to restore the class name:

```
$("table").trigger("destroy", [false, function(table){
    $(table).addClass('tablesorter-bootstrap');
}]);
```

---

Update 2: Ok, that didn't work as expected, you'll need to reapply the "uitheme" widget, but since the destroy method removes the API, I'll update the destroy method in the repository and have it working in the next udpate.

Comment: Thanx Mottie...do I need to manually clear the cache map as well like with a "delete table.config.cache" line in the callback function?  With 7000 row table the assume the cache could be quite large as well.

Comment: Hmm, yeah it looks like you'll need to clear the cache too... I'll fix that in the next update too!

Comment: Actually, you can probably just go ahead and delete the entire table config: `delete table.config`

Comment: Thank-you Mottie for your help and pointing me in the right direction! I found out after destroying most of tablesorter's cache and removing knockoutjs bindings was not enough.  The culprit ended up being the little color image I had inside each cell of a 5 column by 7000 row table.  Once I removed some of the little color images from some columns, phantomjs was able to generate beautiful PDFs of my large table.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: tablesorter v2.16.0-beta is now available with these fixes.